# Error Starting Tomcat 6 with SSL Enabled

Tags: ssl, protocols, tomcat6, http-1.1

I recently got a ssl certificate from godaddy.  I created the keystore properly and put the following into my server.xml:

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="C:\SSLCerts\mykeystore.keystore" keystorePass="password"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I originally had protocol="HTTP/1.1" but I was receiving an error stating that the keystoreFile and the keystorePass didn't have a matching value.  Which caused a binding error on port 8443.  I ran netstat and made sure nothing is running on 8443; did some googling and found to fix that issue to change the protocol as it is above.

After adding that change I'm receiving the following error:

```
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.Http11Protocol-84
43]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start fail
ed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
40)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Jun 21, 2012 1:23:57 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
```

Does anyone have any idea what needs to be done in order to fix this?

Comment: According to <http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html>, should the protocol be "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" instead? Anyway, it is just same as "HTTP/1.1".

Comment: For the original question, did you try `keystoreFile="C:\\SSLCerts\\mykeystore.keystore"` (read: replace every "\" with "\\")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protocol="org.apache.coyote.Http11Protocol"` is not a valid protocol. You want `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"`. Note the extra http11 package you are missing.

That will probably bring you back to the problem with your key store.

Comment: Thanks mark. That was it. I copied it and didn't realize it was missing the package.